# How to split a URL on forward slashes

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a URL path into individual strings in an array.  I've tried a few things and this is as close as I've gotten:

```
<?php   
$url = '/category/subcategory/item';

$output = array(); 
$chunks = explode('/', $url); 
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) 
{
    $output[] = sprintf
    (
        //'<a href="#/%s">%s</a>',
        implode('/', array_slice($chunks, 0, $i + 1)),
        $chunk
    );
}

echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

This returns:

> /category >> /category/subcategory >> /category/subcategory/item

but I would like to try and return

> category >> subcategory >> item

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your desired output it should be this easy:

```
$url = '/category/subcategory/item';
$chunks = array_filter(explode('/', $url));
echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $chunks);
```

`array_filter` removes the empty element(s).

Combining *newboyhun*'s and *Dagon*'s suggestions:

```
echo str_replace('/', ' &gt;&gt; ', trim($url, '/'));
```

Comment: Note that the second one will not remove the empty elements which are in the middle of the `$url` string.

Comment: Ah. I haven't done any PHP for 10 years. I'm very rusty and clearly have a lot of learning to do. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: i deleted my comment, clearer just to leave this answer for future finders

Comment: @user: There shouldn't be any 'empty' elements in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you implode after exploding? So confusing.

Use this:

```
$output = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
echo implode(' &gt;&gt; ', $output);
```

This removes slashes at the start of the string and at the end.